# New Thread out of GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I want to start an endless loop in my Caller class with a start button, and also stop it with stop button out of my gui class. My problem is that I think I need a new thread for the endless loop. And I don't know how I could implement it in my code. Please give me some expert hints. I hope that it is clear what I want to know and what my problem is.

My GUI class:

```
public class GUI implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame;
JPanel panel;
JButton numberBtn;
JLabel actNumberLabel;
JLabel entryNumber;
JButton startBtn;
JButton stopBtn;
static GUI ui;
private boolean run = false;

private String adminTelNumber = "006123456";
private JTextField textEntryNumber;

public GUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("Caller GUI");
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 70);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    startBtn = new JButton("Start");
    startBtn.setBounds(274, 11, 89, 23);
    startBtn.addActionListener(this);
    panel_1.add(startBtn);

    stopBtn = new JButton("Stop");
    stopBtn.setBounds(274, 36, 89, 23);
    stopBtn.addActionListener(this);
    panel_1.add(stopBtn);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    panel_2.setBounds(0, 70, 434, 120);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_2);
    panel_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

    JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
    panel_3.setBounds(0, 190, 434, 71);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_3);
    panel_3.setLayout(null);

    JLabel entryNumber = new JLabel("Telefonnummer eingeben:");
    entryNumber.setBounds(10, 11, 183, 14);
    panel_3.add(entryNumber);

    textEntryNumber = new JTextField();
    textEntryNumber.setBounds(10, 25, 112, 20);
    panel_3.add(textEntryNumber);
    textEntryNumber.setColumns(10);

    numberBtn = new JButton("Übernehmen");
    numberBtn.setBounds(132, 24, 107, 23);
    numberBtn.addActionListener(this);
    panel_3.add(numberBtn);

    actNumberLabel = new JLabel("Derzeitige Signalisierung auf: " + adminTelNumber);
    actNumberLabel.setBounds(10, 46, 369, 14);
    panel_3.add(actNumberLabel);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == numberBtn){
        adminTelNumber = textEntryNumber.getText();
        actNumberLabel.setText("Derzeitige Signalisierung auf: " + adminTelNumber);
        textEntryNumber.setText("");
    }   
    if(e.getSource() == startBtn) {
        run = true;
        Caller.call(ui, 90000, 45);
    }
    if(e.getSource() == stopBtn) {
        run = false;
    }
}

public synchronized String getAdminTelNumber() {
    return adminTelNumber;
}

public synchronized boolean getRun() {
    return run;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        ui = new GUI();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And my endless loop class:

```
public class Caller {

static String number = null;

public static void call(GUI ui, int sleepTime, int standardLeadTime) {
    ArrayList<Integer> alarmTaskIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> doneTasksList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> doneAlarmTasksList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> taskIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (ui.getRun()) {

        doneTasksList = wakeUpCall(taskIdList, doneTasksList, standardLeadTime);
        doneAlarmTasksList = alarmCall(alarmTaskIdList, doneAlarmTasksList, ui);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: [This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For long running tasks use [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) as demonstrated here (note the comments):

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {

    private JButton startBtn, stopBtn;
    private Caller caller;

    public GUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Caller GUI");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        startBtn = new JButton("Start");
        startBtn.addActionListener(this);
        panel_1.add(startBtn);

        stopBtn = new JButton("Stop");
        stopBtn.addActionListener(this);
        stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
        panel_1.add(stopBtn);
        frame.add(panel_1);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == startBtn) {
            caller = new Caller(); //create swing worker 
            caller.execute(); // run it 
            stopBtn.setEnabled(true); //disable, enable buttons 
            startBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
        if(e.getSource() == stopBtn) {
            caller.stop();
            stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            startBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GUI();
    }
}

class Caller extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{

    private int counter = 0;
    private boolean isStoped = false;

    void stop() {isStoped = true; }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

        while (! isStoped ) {
            System.out.println(counter ++); //just print values 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {   e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The main benefits of using `SwingWorker` are :
-Your gui remains responsive (long running tasks on [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), block it)
-You can get intermediate results from the `SwingWorker` (get infromation from it and use it in your gui)
Note that each instance of a `SwingWorker` can only be run once, so it can not be "restarted". You have to create new instance as the code demonstrates.

Comment: one more question...how can i get data from the gui? for example, the Swingworker is currently running an want to access new changes from gui. In my example, you can change the adminTelNumber, and the running thread should access the current number.

Comment: You can simply use a setter in `Caller`  and use it : `caller.setadminTelNumber(287234);` for more help / question please  use a new post, and comment here (so'll get a message and relate to it)